# Is this stump hosting Laetiporus Cincinnatus coniferous?

Tags: tree-identification, mushrooms

I believe I have found a specimen of Laetiporus Cincinnatus growing on a coniferous stump. Identifying features pointing towards Cincinnatus include the white pore surface, the pink tone of the upper edge, the near-white young margins, and the location of Northern New England. Below is a magnified transverse view of a sample of the host stump. Do note the stump is rotten, and has been dead at least a year. **This question is not a mushroom ID question, it is a wood ID question. I need to know if I have misidentified this stump as a conifer.** [image: transverse view of the host stump under magnification]

However, the dichotomous key of https://www.mushroomexpert.com/laetiporus.html suggest that Cincinnatus only grow on hardwoods, and other Laetiporus grow on conifers. This source does not suggest that any white pored Laetiporus grow on conifers.

http://www.minnesotaseasons.com/Fungi/White-Pored_Chicken_of_the_Woods.html states this about the growing conditions of L. Cincinnatus: "It is found on the ground at the base of standing, living or dead oaks, rarely on other hardwoods, never on conifers", and lastly, the table of https://botit.botany.wisc.edu/toms_fungi/jul2001.html agrees with the former two sites.

**Have I misidentified the stump? Or are the growing habits simply not as concrete as sources seem to believe?**. The stump is incredibly rotten, however I would expect some hint of vessels if this were a deciduous tree.

Also attached, photos of the mushroom in question, from the front, back, and below.
[image: mushroom viewed from the front]
[image: mushroom viewed from the back]
[image: mushroom viewed from below]

Comment: I found one on a conifer in Alaska. I read somewhere that it is a different sub species found in the Northwest.